# Elasticsearch duplicate by date timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch

I make a query to a server in which it has duplicate data by date.
I know that the base would have to be debugged, but how could I do a query like the following and return a single record per date. I clarify the dates are duplicated:

```
    {
        "query":{"bool":{
            "must":[
                {"range":{"@timestamp":{"lte": "2021-09-21T23:10:00.000-03:00","gte": "2021-09-21T23:10:00.000-03:00"}}},
                {"match":{"type.keyword":el_type}}
                ]
            }},
        "size":1000,
        "sort": [{"@timestamp": {"order": "asc"}}],

        "_source":{"includes":["@timestamp",el_var]}
    }
```

Comment: Greetings for you first question! For providing you with best answer, will be good enrich your questions with details. Please - provide example of documents in index, and expected search result. Also will be good to understand if all fields in document are the same - or only @timestamp?

Comment: Do you mean [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html)?